# Google Play Services revision 24

Tags: android, google-play-services

I didn't found any documentation for 24 revision. Perhaps someone knows what changes in this revision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The revision 24 correspond to Google Play Services 7.3

> Highlights in Version 7.3:
>
> - Wear - This release provides you with the ability to advertise and discover the capabilities of devices that are connected in a Wear
>     network, through the new CapabilityApi class. The new ChannelApi class
>     lets you send and receive data bi-directionally from your wearable app
>     on a device to another wearable node. Use the Channel API to send
>     large files for offline access or to stream real-time binary data.
> - Fit - This release provides a new HistoryApi.readDailyTotal() method for you to get aggregated daily data for a given data type.
>     This release also introduces data types for recording granular
>     nutrition information including protein, fat, cholesterol, and more.
> - Location - This release adds a maximum wait time for location updates. By calling the new setMaxWaitTime() method and passing in a
>     value at least double the value requested with the setInterval()
>     method, the system can batch location updates together, reducing
>     battery usage and, on some devices, improving location accuracy. In
>     addition, you can use the new LocationCallback class to be notified
>     when the device location has changed or can no longer be determined.

You can find more information on [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html?utm_campaign=playservices73-415)